# Determining filetype of file in assets folder

Tags: android, directory, filesystems, assets

Question: How do you programmatically distinguish between directories and regular files in the assets folder?

When using AssetManager to access files in the assets folder, it seems impossible to determine if a file is in fact a file or a directory. You get the list of files from the `list` method and then open the file using the `open` method. I thought perhaps using the `openFd` method to get the asset file descriptor (and then subsequently requesting the normal file descriptor) would provide me some information. But requesting the file descriptor for a directory results in an IOException (which makes sense since what would it mean for a directory to have a file descriptor...?).

Currently I'm relying on that IOException (resulting from attemptng to open a directory in the assets folder) in order to determine if a file is in fact a directory. (Opening a regular file works just fine). This seems like a bad idea. Any other suggestions to distinguish between a file and a directory?

Comment: How are you arranging your files into the asset directory? Can't you keep files 
separated from folders instead of mixing all toghether?

Comment: Agreed. You're the one who is putting in the contents of the `assets/` directory. Hence, you should not need to be guessing what is and is not a directory.

Comment: No matter how you place your files in the `assets/` folder, this problem exists. The `list` method sends back a `String[]` array of all files <b>and</b> directories located in the requested directory path (e.g. `image.jpg`, `music.mp3`, `Tools`). If you want to have any sort of directory structure inside of `assets/`, you will encounter this issue.

Comment: All the more so you have to keep things separated. IMHO this is a design problem. Is there a valid reason that you cant organize your files in something like this? assets/audio/*.mp3 assets/pics/*.png
Now i'm curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments on your post. But to answer your question, make a File object pointed at the assets directory 
`File root = new File("path/to/directory");`

Then you can extract all its sub files and directories like this 
`File[] files = root.listFiles();`

Once you have the list you can determine what is what using File.isDirectory().

As for determining file types, that is as simple as using String.subString() to grab the character's following the last period.

hope this helps